# Why does cut grass cause allergies?

Tags: botany, allergies

I know that cut grass from a lawn or field can cause allergies in some people. 
I also know that most plant allergies are due to plant pollen.

However, most people do not allow their lawn grass to flower, and therefore, any allergy from cut grass is likely not due to pollen.

So, what exactly in the grass is causing the allergy?

I did a google search but only found evidence and info for grass-*pollen* allergies.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

www.allergicliving.com claims that the cause to such an allergy is not the grass but is **actually mold**:

> Often patients will have allergy symptoms with fresh cut grass...That's not grass pollen allergy, that may be mold allergy from the molds being stirred up.

The site also mentions that simply having the **physical presence of lawn mower "dust"** in one's nose may cause symptoms.

Source: www.allergicliving.com/2010/07/02/outdoor-allergy-grass-allergy-attack